# Put flatlist inside a table

Tags: react-native, api, url, html-table, flatlist

I just made a table in react native and would like to put data from an API inside it. I tried to become the table with a flatlist, but allas, it's not working. Here is my code:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Rows, Col, Cols, Cell } from 'react-native-table-component';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList } from 'react-native-web';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      HeadTable: ['Title', 'Release Year'],
      DataTable: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  async getMovies(){
    try{
      const response = await
      fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json');
      const json = await response.json();
      this.setState({ DataTable: json.movies});
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }finally{
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMovies();
  }

 render(){
   const {HeadTable, DataTable, isLoading} = this.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
            data={DataTable}
            keyExtractor={({id}; index) => id}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ffa1d2'}}>
              <Row data={HeadTable} style={styles.HeadStyle} textStyle={styles.TableText}/>
              <Rows data={item.title} textStyle={styles.TableText}/>
              </Table>
            )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
 }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { 
      flex: 1,
      padding: 18,
      paddingTop: 35,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff' 
    },
    HeadStyle: { 
      height: 50,
      alignContent: "center",
      backgroundColor: '#ffe0f0'
    },
    TableText: { 
      margin: 10
    }
  });
```

If there is a way to put to data from the API inside the table without the FlatList that would be even better. I'm working on this for a while now and it's really frustraiting to not get even these simple things to work.

Comment: What is the error or problem that you're having?

Comment: Basically, I want to put the values of an API inside a table, in react native. I'm working on this for far too long now. But I don't know how to do this. I feel like I have searched the entire internet for a week now. I can only find stuff on how to do this in reactJS not react native.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what the problem is. Are you getting errors? Is the layout wrong? Please describe the problem.